# How to get python packages in AWS Lambda without uploading zip file or using EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-efs

I have implemented getting packages from Elastic File System (EFS) mounted in Ubuntu EC2 instance but the API gateway seems to be slow when calling it multiple times and also the API runs into a timeout error frequently. Since my packages (600MB) exceed the lambda limit of 250MB I cannot upload the packages as a zip file in Lambda.

1. Is there any other way to use the python packages in lambda? Uploading zip or EFS doesn't seem to work for me
2. Has anyone faced the same problem with the slowness of the EFS? Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider that lambda is simple a **wrong tool for your use-case**. Lambda is meant for quick, short running and small programs. With 600MB of dependencies you are far from what lambda can handle.

In such cases usually ppl choose to use **ECS** to deploy their applications as containers, or traditional **EC2** instances.

Comment: Is it possible to call the python file in EC2 via API gateway? API is important for me as the API will be used on our website to do some analytical operations.